# $χ(G) = 2$ if and only if $χ_f (G) = 2$.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

Can anyone help with this?

''Show that $χ(G)=2$ if and only if $χ_f(G)=2$.''

$χ(G)$ is a chromatic number and $χ_f(G)$ is a fractional chromatic number.

---

I tried to proove:

($=>$)

$χ(G)=2$  $⟺$ G is bipartite and $E(G)≠∅$  $=>$   $ω(G)=2$  $=>$ $χ_f(G)=2$

($<=$)

Suppose, that $χ_f(G)=2$.
Then  $ω(G)≤2$.

(We can suppose that  $ω(G)=2$, because if  $ω(G)=1$, then $χ(G)=1$  $=>$  $χ_f(G)=1$ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $G$ is a connected graph and we give each vertex a subset of size $k$ of $\{1,...,2k\}$ such that adjacent vertices get disjoint sets, show that there is some subset $S$ such that all vertices get either $S$ or $S^c$.